# Laravel - How to join 2 tables from different db connection?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I have an application that use 2 databases. I need to create a query that joins a table from one database with a table form another but I don't know how to do that.

So, I have a connection name `mysql` and `phc`. I can communicate with both with no problems.

Now, I'm trying to do this query:

```
$artigos = DB::connection('phc')->table('st')
        ->join('mysql.cart', 'mysql.cart.id_item', '=', 'st.ststamp')
        ->select('st.ststamp', 'st.ref', 'st.design', 'st.imagem', 'mysql.cart.qtt')
        ->where('mysql.carts.id_user','=',Auth::id())
        ->paginate(10);
```

But returns me : `General error: 20018 Invalid object name 'mysql.cart'`

I want to access connection mysql table cart and connection phc table st.

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: I think this is not realy, because you need select database in begin connect. In mysql cli application you type `use database_name` and work in this database, for work in other database you need `use other database_name2` and work this. I think yout need run directly query with out eloquen. for example see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426929/can-we-use-join-for-two-different-database-tables

Comment: and sorry for my English

Comment: Are your databases located on different servers?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423603/join-two-mysql-tables-in-different-databases-on-the-same-server-with-laravel-elo

Comment: checkout this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63051014/10539212), hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the connection('phc') and prefix the php tables as you do with mysql tables.
You are choosing the connection, so the query builder should understand that it would prefix your tables with the connection names. 
So, when you type 'mysql.cart' the query builder will do 'phc.mysql.cart'.

```
$artigos = DB::table('phc.st')
        ->join('mysql.cart', 'mysql.cart.id_item', '=', 'phc.st.ststamp')
        ->select('phc.st.ststamp', 'phc.st.ref', 'phc.st.design', 'phc.st.imagem', 'mysql.cart.qtt')
        ->where('mysql.carts.id_user','=',Auth::id())
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: If I try do that returns me Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mysql.cart' doesn't exist @FábioNunes

Comment: Is your databases on the same instance?

Answer (score -2):

this is my code for joining two table:

```
$departmetns = DB::table('department')
      ->select('department.*', 'faculty.name as f_name')
      ->join('faculty','department.faculty_id', '=' ,'faculty.id')
       ->get();
```

in your case

```
USE DB;

DB::table('st')
    ->select('st.ststamp', 'st.ref', 'st.design', 'st.imagem', 'cart.qtt')
    ->join('cart', 'st.ststamp', '=', 'cart.id_item')
    ->where('carts.id_user','=',Auth::id())
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: This is not between different databases @KhalilDaNish

Comment: I know this is for two table from the same database.