# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::join(), 1 passed in

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using two different databases while fetching data i am getting the above error.

```
$response = ProductCode::select('users.name as customer_name', 'productcode', 'luckydraw_ode', 'activated_at', 'users.mobile_number')
            ->join(DB::Connection('mysql'))
            ->table('users', 'users.id', '=', 'productcodes.sales_by')
            ->where('sales_by', 7)
            ->get();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423603/join-two-mysql-tables-in-different-databases-on-the-same-server-with-laravel-elo

Comment: You are joining Db Connection ? You should join only tables.

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'oppazzgiftcode_app_OppazZ'@'localhost' for table 'productcode'

Comment: @swatantra it's db config problems. check your configs