# Laravel - Join tables across 2 databases (same server)

Tags: php, laravel, database, psql

I'm trying to join 2 tables in 2 databases. But using the common solutions don't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. Here is what I have:

My connections:

```
    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'data'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
    ],

    'auth' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_AUTH', 'authentication'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
    ]
```

The Laravel query I'm trying to run:

```
    Files::where('sender_id',$userId)
  ->join('authentication.users as users','Policies.sender_id','=','users.id')
  ->select('*')
  ->get();
```

The table `Files` belong to database `data`.

But this gives me an error `SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "authentication.users" does not exist`

I know the connection to the `authentication` table works since I can do this

```
DB::connection('auth')->table('users')->whereIn('id', '123')->first();
```

I've tried replacing `authentication` with `auth` but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using query builder :

```
$query = DB::table('database1.table1 as dt1')->leftjoin('database2.table2 as dt2', 'dt2.ID', '=', 'dt1.ID');        
$output = $query->select(['dt1.*','dt2.*'])->get();
```

using Eloquent model option:

```
Model1::where('postID',$postID)
      ->join('database2.table2 as db2','Model1.id','=','db2.id')
      ->select(['Model1.*','db2.firstName','db2.lastName'])
      ->orderBy('score','desc')
      ->get();
```

This might be a duplicate ask. Pls refer [Join two MySQL tables in different databases on the same server with Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423603/join-two-mysql-tables-in-different-databases-on-the-same-server-with-laravel-elo)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work: $query = DB::table('database1.table1 as dt1') (in my case authentication.token). It just gives an error - Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "authentication.token" does not exist