# Multiple database join laravel

Tags: php, arrays, union, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

How to join multiple database table. in laravel 8 or 9

I want to get result of multiple database join i have tried

```
 $app_details = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('user_leaves')
        ->join('mysql.users', 'mysql.users.id', '=', 'user_leaves.user_id')
        ->select('user_leaves.leave_type')
        ->get();

user_leaves table from  database 2 and users table from database  1
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423603/join-two-mysql-tables-in-different-databases-on-the-same-server-with-laravel-elo help?